# Pandas compare nullable Int64 to regular ints

Tags: pandas

I noticed that if you try to compare a nullable int column (pd.Int64Dtype) to a regular int column, null values return NA rather than false. This is different than how np.nan behaves -> np.nan > 0 returns false.

Is there any way to enable comparison that returns False for everything, rather than pd.NA?

Comment: Kindly add example dataframes with output

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, pd.NA]})` and `df["col2"] = df["col2"].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`, then `print((df["col1"] > df["col2"]).fillna(False))`?